# From node how can I check if a remote server is running ssh?

Tags: node.js

I have a list of IPs for server on my network, I need to check if they are running ssh or not from within node. How can I go about this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depends how deep you want this check to run. You could simply check if the port 22 is open, if you want to see if something is running there, or perhaps you have to try to connect to establish it's really ssh protocol, and maybe portscan all ports for it or whatever.

There are ssh client libs like ssh or more general network scanners like netty.

Do npm search ssh client or npm search port scanning or npm search nmap for extended selection of libs that can do that.